# Implement lazy loading on table using aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-iteration

I'm trying to implement the lazy loading to the aura component and Accounts record maybe 10 or 100 or 500 and I do not have the ability to play with soql since this component sits as a child and the Account List is being passed.

Any pointers how should I do? so when the component loads I want to show only 50 records and as the user scroll down then load the another 50 from the `accounts` list

Here is the child component looks like.

```
<aura:component >
     
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List"/>

    <!--Component Start-->
    <div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
            <table class="slds-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-record="Name"></th>
                        <th data-record="AccountNumber"></th>
                        <th data-record="Industry"></th>
                        <th data-record="Phone"></th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
                            <tr class="slds-hint-parent"> 
                                <th data-label="Name"> {!acc.Name}  </th>
                                <td data-label="Account Number"> {!acc.AccountNumber </td>
                                <td data-label="Industry">{!acc.Industry}  </td>
                                <td data-label="Phone">{!acc.Phone}  </td> 
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody> 
            </table> 
    </div>
    <!--Component End--> 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I'm wondering about the javascript `slice` method should use that for lazy loading?

Comment: are you looking for the infinite scroll? if yes, check if this article [Load data in row on scrolling] (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005U3aQAE)  helps you.

Comment: in the above example you are using the lightining datatable and if you look at my question, I'm using the table

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a lazy load logic when div is scrolled.

Fix the `height` of the div containing the table. Allow scroll on overflow.
Use the `onscroll` event handler to provide custom logic to load next set of data.

Use **`accounts`** attribute to set all Account data.
Use **`dataToShow`** attribute to show Account data. Initially only add **50** accounts from **`accounts`** to **`dataToShow`**.

```
<aura:attribute name="count" type="integer" default="50" /> //to maintain count
<aura:attribute name="allAccountsLoaded" type="boolean" default="false" /> //to check if all account data is loaded
<aura:attribute name="dataToShow" type="List" default="false" /> //to show data in table

<div style="height: 300px;overflow-x: scroll;" onscroll="{!c.handleScroll}">
<!--insert table here-->
</div>
```

In JavaScript use the scroll event handler:

```
handleScroll(event , component){
        var scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop
        var scrollHeight = event.target.scrollHeight
        var clientHeight = event.target.clientHeight
        
        var count = component.get("v.count")
        var allAccounts = component.get("v.accounts")
        var allAccountsLoaded = component.get("v.allAccountsLoaded")
        
        var dataToShow = component.get("v.dataToShow")

        //console.log('scrollTop: ',scrollTop)
        //console.log('scrollHeight: ',scrollHeight)
        //console.log('clientHeight: ',clientHeight)
        
        if(((scrollHeight - clientHeight) <= (scrollTop + 10)) && !allAccountsLoaded){
            //load next set of 50 records
            var nextSetOfData = allAccounts.splice(count , 50)
            dataToShow.push(nextSetOfData)
            component.set("v.dataToShow", dataToShow)
            
            //logic to check if all data has been loaded
            if(dataToShow.length === allAccounts.length){
                allAccountsLoaded = true;
                component.set("v.allAccountsLoaded", allAccountsLoaded)
            }
        }
}
```